# Получение десериализованных данных

Tags: c#, .net

Почему не возвращаются данные, полученные после десериализации?

```
string Result = WCFClientOpen.GetProcessProperty(ParameterType, ParameterRequest);
if (Result != "Not")
{
    XmlSerializer XmlData = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WCF_Client.Information));
    using (StringReader ReconvertString = new StringReader(Result))
    {
        object BufData = XmlData.Deserialize(ReconvertString);
        WCF_Client.Information GetDataContracts = (WCF_Client.Information)BufData;
        Values.ArrayPropertyWCF = GetDataContracts.ArrayProperty;
    }
    ValueProcessInfo.InitializationConnect = true;
}
else if (Result == "Not")
{
    ConfigurationsPrograms.Message.MessageInformation("ProcessInfo", "GetDataServer", "");
    ValueProcessInfo.MainChannelSending.Close();
}
```

> значения переменной BufData всегда равны null хотя схожий код прекрасно работает в другом методе, а вот в переменная ReconvertString заполнена.

Что за бред и как его решить?

Comment: Недостаточно информации для анализа. Привидите код к минимальному воспроизводимому примеру. Если останутся вопросы, пишите. А сейчас в вопросе ноль информации: нет ни десериализуемого класса, ни XML.

Comment: @Discord: спасибо, что отформатировали :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема была в двух DataTable (извиняюсь за то что не обозначил типы переменных) видимо больше одного использовать нельзя, вкратце - DataSet спас

Comment: Что-то что вопрос, что ответ - на какой-то бред похожи... Зачем передавать XML через WCF в строковой форме? Причем тут вообще DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

`Deserialize` возвращает `null` в случае проблем с десериализацией. 
С ходу могу предположить, что структура XML не совпадает с тем, как Вы настроили Ваш класс (например, перепутаны элементы с атрибутами). Это самая распространенная ошибка. Но может быть и что-то другое, для точного ответа нужно больше информации.